# Strange Behavior Python 3.8 Walrus Operator: chained inequalities

Tags: python-3.8, walrus-operator

The following code:

```
a,b=1,2
print((x:=a)<2<(z:=b) or z>1>x)
print((x:=a)<1<(y:=b) or y>1>x)
```

gives the following output:

```
False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/phili/PycharmProjects/ML 1/CodingBat exercises.py", line 56, in <module>
    print((x:=a)<1<(y:=b) or y>1>x)
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

which seems absolutely inconsistent. Some variations like
`(x:=1)>=2>(y:=9) or y>=2>x`
also gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

Does anyone know what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently chained operators short-circuit. You can see this in this example code:

```
>>> 1 < 1 < print("Nope")
False  # Nothing else is printed
```

This is likely because

```
a < b < c
```

Is essentially a short-hand of

```
a < b and b < c
```

And `and` short-circuits:

```
>>> False and print("Nope")
False
```

This means that since the left-hand check is False, the right side is never evaluated, so `y` is never set.